# Getting the correct href of the clicked link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html menu:

```
<div id="menulinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link4">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I need to write a javascript - can't use jQuery - that gives me a href of the clicked anchor link. That's what I did:

```
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  var clickedLink = a[o];
  clickedLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var b = clickedLink.getAttribute("href");
    alert(b);
  });
}
```

It works, but I always get '#link4' as an answer in the alertbox, no matter which link I click. Can you tell me, what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `clickedLink` is getting overwritten with the subsequent value each time the `for loop` iterates and by the time the link is clicked, `clickedLink` has already been assigned the last `href` value.

I'm guessing your confusion results from assuming Javascript has block scoping when it actually uses [lexical scoping](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/).  (You might read up on [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) too...)

One solution is to bind each value assigned to `clickedLink` to an Immediately Invoked Function...

```
for ( var o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  var clickedLink = a[o];
  (function(clickedLink) { 
    clickedLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var b = clickedLink.getAttribute("href");
      alert(b);
    });
  })(clickedLink);
}
```

Comment: An alternative in my answer is to wrap the loop body in an IIFE and skip the parameter passing. It's essentially the same as this, obviously, but I'm presenting it as an alternative. Ultimately the function-based answers are all the same, I suppose.

Comment: I do like your answer @DaveNewton, and I think it's an improvement on my answer.  Just gave it a +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element related to the event with `this` from within the handler. Otherwise you are referencing the last element that was assigned to `clickedLink`

Also, you can use `querySelectorAll` to quickly select the links. But if the links change the list that `querySelectorAll` returns will not change, so you would have to select the links again. `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not an HTMLCollection, and therefore cannot be accessed using array methods like `forEach`, but in this situation it will function perfectly.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("#menulinks a");
for (var o = 0; o < a.length; o++) {
    a[o].addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert(this.href);
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="menulinks">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way around the scoping issue; wrap the loop body in an IIFE. It's basically @sfletche's answer, but "up" one level, and doesn't require the parameter:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var o = 0; o < a.length; o++) {
  (function() {
    var clickedLink = a[o];
    clickedLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var b = clickedLink.getAttribute("href");
      alert(b);
    });
  })();
}
```

```html
<div id="menulinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link4">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I wouldn't *do* it this way, but it's an alternative that might be easier to follow if you're just getting into closures and/or IIFEs.

Answer (score 0):

The link `clickedLink` refers to is getting overwritten with each iteration and by the time the link is clicked it refers to the last link.

You can fix it very simply by changing

```
var b = clickedLink.getAttribute("href");
```

to

```
var b = this.getAttribute("href");
```

then it will work:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  var clickedLink = a[o];
  clickedLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var b = this.getAttribute("href");
    alert(b);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="menulinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link4">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or if you want to use the new ES6 features (which work in some modern browsers but not all) then you can do:

```html
<div id="menulinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link4">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  let clickedLink = a[o];
  clickedLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert( clickedLink.getAttribute("href") );
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just discovered [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). Here's what the interpreter thinks your code looks like.

```
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
var clikedLink, o;
for ( o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  clickedLink = a[o];
  clickedLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var b = clickedLink.getAttribute("href");
    alert(b);
  });
}
```

Since `clickedLink` is [closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in the event listener, it will continue to get overwritten on every interation of the loop, hence why every link gives the href of the last `a` tag, because it *is* the last `a` tag.

Here's how you could do it correctly

```
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  a[o].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var b = this.getAttribute("href");
    alert(b);
  }.bind(a[o]));
}
```

Or if you can't use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
var a = document.getElementById("menulinks").getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var o = 0; o < a.length; o++ ) {
  (function(l) {
    l.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var b = l.getAttribute("href");
    alert(b);
  })(a[o]);
}
```

Comment: It's not specifically hoisting, it's scoping, no?

Comment: From MDN: " Hoisting is JavaScript's behavior of moving declarations to the top of a scope (the global scope or the current function scope)." Kind of one in the same in this case.

Comment: I suppose; my objection is probably semantics. I probably just don't think about it anymore and am incapable of explaining it at this point :)

Comment: Similar to my comment on @sfletche's answer; if there's to be an IIFE to wrap things up, I might prefer not bothering to pass a parameter (which I find a little ugly). It's all the same, though.